# Is there a name for a single table space in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I understand that in a table, field is used to refer to a column and record is used to refer to rows.

But is there a name for the intersection between a record and a field? I am talking about a singular value of either a record or field. In Excel, it is called a cell.

i.e.:

```
        Column 1            Column 2
Row 1   Row 1, Column 1     Row 1, Column 2
Row 2   Row 2, Column 1     Row 2, Column 2
Row 3   Row 3, Column 1     Row 3, Column 2

What is row 1, column 1 called?
```

Comment: From a table context --> i.e: in  a table, a record is called a row and a field is called a column.

Comment: It is also called "field." It's rare to use the term "field" to refer to the column as you describe it, but it depends on the context. You could also say "property." "Cell" would also work but is more rare if you're not talking about spreadsheets.

Comment: I think, we can call it record. But, if You want, please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and go to overview part

Comment: If you type in the command `show columns from table` it will list out the "field" names (column names), hence why I believed it was called a field + googled that part of the definition from other sources. Are you saying the word field could be used to refer to both an entire column and a single cell?

Comment: Quoth: An `attribute value` is the entry in a specific column and row, such as "John Doe" or "35".

Comment: Record == Row == Tuple to me. Good link though. Worth reading the links to Tuple & Relation on that page too.

Comment: It says a record is interchangeable with that of a row. Was looking for single value of a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with Element or Value as the most apt.

Comment: Having read deep into the Wikipedia article I think it could be called an attribute (another name for column) value, or column value, but this was pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent notion in SQL because a table is unordered collection of rows. So there are no cells as fixed spaces to be filled with values. For example
if a table has two equal rows those rows can not be distinguished. Sql has rows, columns and values but no cells.